# No man pages available even though clearly there

Tags: fish, manpage

I love the fish shell. It makes perfect sense to me, but there's one problem I've been having.

No matter what I try, I can't get `man` to work. When I type

```
man ls
```

for example, I get `No manual entry for ls`. Same for every other command.

On bash, of course, this would show the man page. My `MANPATH` environment variable is set (points to `/opt/local/share/man/`) which contains exactly the files I would expect.

Any help?

Comment: show the output of `type -a man`

Comment: Also the operating system and fish version would be good to know. Fish overrides man with a function to insert its own man pages, and that used to have some issues, especially on non-mainstream-linux OSen.

Comment: ```
# Defined in /Users/jrush/.config/fish/functions/man.fish @ line 1
function man --description 'Format and display manual pages'
    set -q man_blink
    and set -l blink (set_color $man_blink)
    or set -l blink (set_color -o red)
    < ... removed code >
    command man $argv
end
man is /usr/bin/man
```

Comment: Mac operating system
fish --version
fish, version 3.0.2

Comment: The output of `man -w`, and `stat /opt/local/share/man/man1/ls.1`, would be useful.

Comment: man -w: `/usr/local/Cellar/fish/3.0.2/share/fish/man:/opt/local/share/man/`

Comment: stat: `/opt/local/share/man/man1/ls.1: stat: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have defined `MANPATH` without including any of the system manual directories, so `man` will not search them.

Instead, set `MANPATH` to `/opt/local/share/man:`, which will prepend that directory to the system-determined paths (this is not well-documented in the macOS manual page for `man`).

For example:

```
> env MANPATH="/opt:" man -w
/opt:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/opt/X11/share/man:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/man:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man
> env MANPATH="/opt" man -w
/opt
```

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.